# Changing index reference for Set in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

Is there a way to change the Set indexing from 1 indexed to 0 indexed in Pyomo? It's very difficult to keep everything straight when you are dealing with multiple objects where Pyomo is 1 referenced and everything else from Python is 0 referenced.

The reason for this is to generate a model fitting routine for multiple circuit devices. Instead of recreating the entire model over and over, I want to define it once with an AbstractModel. Then I can just reload the data and resolve for each device.

In my objective function, I'm defining intermediate values using list comprehension. Once these intermediate values are generated, they are now 0 referenced. An example of what I'm doing is below. As you can see, I have to have some parameters declared with [i] and others with [i-1]. It just becomes difficult and confusing when the functions become large. It would make a whole lot more sense if everything was just 0 referenced so that it was consistent with standard Python code. I was hoping there was some easy option or setting to declare whether a Set is 0 or 1 referenced.

`y11intre = [1 / m.Ra[1] + 1 / m.Rb[1] for i in m.n]
y11intim = [m.w[i] * (m.Ca[1] + m.Cb[1]) for i in m.n]
y12intre = ...
...
z11intre = [-y22intim[i-1] * ... for i in m.n]
...
z11re = [m.Rae[1] + z11intre[i-1] for i in m.n]
z11im = [m.w[i] * m.Lae[1] + z11intim[i-1] for i in m.n]`

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the starting and stopping point to `RangeSet` to give you the values you want:

```
m.r = RangeSet(0,5) # [0,1,2,3,4,5]
m.s = RangeSet(0,4) # [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This approach does work if you are dealing with a ConcreteModel. But I am trying to generate an AbstractModel, where the length of this set may not always be the same value. I need to iterate over this set to generate my objective function. When I do this, I get an error for the AbstractModel generation.

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question with the code that isn't working for you and the error message you're seeing? Is there a reason you chose to use an AbstractModel over a ConcreteModel?